# How to write unit test for a MediatR handler C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mediatr

I'm trying to write unit test using Moq framework for one of my MediatR handler. I have the following code. Briefly, what this handler does is that it queries for the given key and returns a response that contains key and its value using EF Core. Also there is a basic cache mechanism. If the key found in cache it is pulled from cache and returned.

Handler

```
public GetConfigByKeyRequestHandler(MyContext context, ICacheProvider cacheProvider, IOptions<CacheConfigs> cacheConfigs)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    this.cacheConfigs = cacheConfigs?.Value;
}


public async Task<ConfigResponse> Handle(GetConfigByKeyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ConfigResponse config;
    if (!await cacheProvider.ExistsAsync(request.Key))
    {
        config = await context.Configs
            .Where(x.ConfigKey.Equals(request.Key))
            .Select(x => 
                    new ConfigResponse {
                        ConfigKey = x.ConfigKey,
                        ConfigValue = x.ConfigValue 
                    })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (config is not null)
        {
            await cacheProvider.PutAsync(new CacheItem<ConfigResponse>(request.Key, config), new CacheOptions
            {
                ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheConfigs.ExpireAfterInMinutes).TotalMilliseconds,
                ExpireInactive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheConfigs.ExpireInActiveInMinutes).TotalMilliseconds
            }); 
        }
        return config;
    }

    config = await cacheProvider.PullAsync<ConfigResponse>(request.Key);
    return config;
}
```

I have thought that I should cover 2 different scenarios:

1. When the key found in the  cache
2. When the key is not found in cache and it's returned from DbContext.

Unit tests

```
private Mock<ICacheProvider> cacheProviderMock;
private IOptions<CacheConfigs> cacheConfigs;
public GetConfigByKeyRequestHandlerTests()
{
    cacheProviderMock = new Mock<ICacheProvider>();
    cacheConfigs = Options.Create(
        new CacheConfigs
        {
            ExpireAfterInMinutes = 3,
            ExpireInActiveInMinutes = 3
        });
}

[Fact]
public async Task GetConfigByKeyHandler_WhenKeyIsCached_ShouldReturnConfigByKey()
{
    // arrange 
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("MyInMemoryDatabase").Options;
    var configItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => new Config
    {
        ConfigKey = $"key{x}",
        ConfigValue = $"value{x}"
    });

    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        await context.Configs.AddRangeAsync(configItems);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

   
    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        cacheProviderMock.Setup(x => x.ExistsAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
        cacheProviderMock.Setup(x => x.PullAsync<ConfigResponse>("key2"))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ConfigResponse
            {
                ConfigKey = "key2",
                ConfigValue = "value2"
            }));
        var getConfigByKeyHandler = new GetConfigByKeyRequestHandler(context, cacheProviderMock.Object, cacheConfigs);
        var getConfigByKeyRequest = new GetConfigByKeyRequest("key2");
        // act
        var result = await getConfigByKeyHandler.Handle(getConfigByKeyRequest, CancellationToken.None);

        // assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal("key2", result.ConfigKey);
    }

}
...
...
```

With the same logic, I have one more test for the other scenario that when key is not cached

```
...
...

[Fact]
public async Task GetConfigByKeyHandler_WhenKeyIsNotCached_ShouldReturnConfigByKey()
{
    // arrange 
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("MyInMemoryDatabase").Options;
    var configItems = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(x => new Config
    {
        ConfigKey = $"key{x}",
        ConfigValue = $"value{x}"
    });

    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        await context.Configs.AddRangeAsync(configItems);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    
    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        cacheProviderMock.Setup(x => x.ExistsAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(false));
        var getConfigByKeyHandler = new GetConfigByKeyRequestHandler(context, cacheProviderMock.Object, cacheConfigs);
        var getConfigByKeyRequest = new GetConfigByKeyRequest("key2");
        // act
        var result = await getConfigByKeyHandler.Handle(getConfigByKeyRequest, CancellationToken.None);

        // assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal("key2", result.ConfigKey);
    }


}
```

I have written 2 unit tests that covers the scenarios that I have mentioned above, but I'm not sure that they are reasonable ones and I'm not sure it should be tested like this way. Do you have any suggestions what/how should I write tests for the handler I shared above?

Comment: I guess since you have working code, you might find codereview.stackexchange.com a better site for improving it. You'll likely get opinions like 1. Since you aren't really mocking the DbContext, you have an integration test, not a unit test, 2. DRY up the UseInMemoryDatabase Arrange setups 3. MediatR might be overkill for 'QueryHandlers' and 4. Consider using the [Cache Aside pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside) to DRY up your imperative cache management branches. But of course, these are all just opinions.

Comment: Hey. I had the same situation in my project. I decided to divide logic on integration tests and unit tests. I tested whole `MediatR` logic using integration tests. Unit tests helped me to test logic inside handlers. As a results you can combine two approahces of tests to achive better results :)